# Labels disappear from Google chart when animation occurs

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-visualization

When my chart animates to display new data, the labels on the columns disappear and are not rendered again. All the the data is being imported correctly and displayed on the columns. The label data is only displayed on the initial render of the chart.

The success handler returns 'values', an array of three numbers, for example: [10, 8, 2] and is working correctly.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="genderChart" style="overflow: hidden"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initChart);
    
    var chart;
    var options = {
      legend: {position: "none"},
      chartArea: {width:'100%'},
      animation: {duration: 1000, easing: 'out'}
    };

    function initChart() {
      chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('genderChart'));
      drawGenderChart();
    }

    function drawGenderChart() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (values){
        genderData = values;
      }).getGenderData();

      label00 = JSON.stringify(genderData[0]);
      label01 = JSON.stringify(genderData[1]);
      label02 = JSON.stringify(genderData[2]);

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Gender');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Students');
      data.addColumn({role: 'style'});
      data.addColumn({role: 'annotation'});

      data.addRows([
        ['Male', genderData[0], '#9fc5e8', label00],
        ['Female', genderData[1], '#d5a6bd', label01],
        ['Non-binary', genderData[2], '#b7b7b7', label02]
      ]);

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    setInterval(drawGenderChart, 1000);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Apps Script:

```
function getGenderData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Console");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A3:C4");
  var values = range.getValues();
  return values.flat();
}
```

Comment: The code is uncomplete, the `doGet` and `getGenderData` functions are missing. Ref. [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I see the difference in our code that is leading to the confusion in the output. In my original code I have 'setInterval(drawGenderChart, 1000);' so the chart can receive updated data from the sheet. When you add this line to your solution, you will see that the labels disappear when the animation occurs.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: I think that in this case, my answer was not useful for your situation. So, I have to delete my answer. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your situation, I would like to try to think of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.script.run` runs asynchronously, so you need to wait for it to finish,
before drawing the chart.

to accomplish, simply place the rest of the code within the success handler...

```
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (values){
    genderData = values;

    label00 = JSON.stringify(genderData[0]);
    label01 = JSON.stringify(genderData[1]);
    label02 = JSON.stringify(genderData[2]);

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Gender');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Students');
    data.addColumn({role: 'style'});
    data.addColumn({role: 'annotation'});

    data.addRows([
      ['Male', genderData[0], '#9fc5e8', label00],
      ['Female', genderData[1], '#d5a6bd', label01],
      ['Non-binary', genderData[2], '#b7b7b7', label02]
    ]);

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }).getGenderData();
```

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat. I noticed that the labels still disappear, but only while the animation is occurring. After the animation completes, the labels are shown again. Is this the expected behavior when using animations? Any way to make the labels persist during the animation?

Comment: that is the expected behavior, you could bring it up with google, [here](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues)...